# Show $\sum \frac{n}{2^n + n} <\frac 32$

Tags: inequality

Let $n\in \mathbb N^{+}$,show that
$$\dfrac{1}{2+1}+\dfrac{2}{2^2+2}+\dfrac{3}{2^3+3}+\cdots+\dfrac{n}{2^n+n}<\dfrac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Please show us what you have tried/your own thoughts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using that $\sum_{n=k}^\infty n 2^{-n} = (k+1)2^{1-k}$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n + n} < \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{6} + \frac{3}{11} + \frac{4}{20} + \frac{5}{37} + \sum_{n=6}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}\\ = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{6} + \frac{3}{11} + \frac{4}{20} + \frac{5}{37} + \frac{7}{32}  = \frac{291727}{195360} < \frac{3}{2}.
$$

Also ugly, but also works.

Comment: Not ugly at all! +1

Comment: @zhoraster I don't see how you can justify the proof of the last step without at least some cumbersome computation.  You've left out some crucial steps at the end.  That's not good enough!

Comment: @RumpyPumpy, shame on me and on those 10 persons who had upvoted! $291727\cdot 2 = 583... < 586.. =195360\cdot 3$.

Answer (score 5):

I will suggest an ugly solution and I hope someone will refine it.

The ugly part is that you should check your inequality for $1\leq n\leq 8$.

After doing that you can prove using $2$ induction that for $n\geq 9$ the following stronger inequality holds:

$$\sum \frac{n}{2^n+n}\leq \frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{n}.$$

I admit, it's ugly but it works.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{2^n+n} = \frac{31}{33}+\sum_{n\geq 4}\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k+1} n^k 2^{-nk}\leq \frac{31}{33}+\frac{5}{8}-\frac{173}{1728}+\frac{25157}{1229312}<\frac{3}{2}. $$